# Split 2d array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, split, 2d

I have a 2d array as such :

```
   Array
        (
          [0] => Array([nid] => 5),
          [1] => Array([nid] => 6),
          [2] => Array([nid] => 7),......
```

I want to `split` the `array` by key into two parts. 
For example I want to split the array at key = 1. 
I need the result as two arrays `arr1` holding key `0 & 1` and `arr2` holding key `2`.
Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Perhaps look at the [array_slice()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) function

Comment: Thanks eventually array_splice helped me

Answer (score -1):

```
$arr1 = array_slice($input, 0, 2); 
//array holding elements and keys of array [0] and [1]
$arr2 = array_slice($input, 2);  
//array holding elements and keys of array [2] to n
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12619068)

Comment: @RuchishParikh I thought the requirement was "the result as two arrays arr1 holding key 0 & 1 and arr2 holding key 2"? My apology if I misunderstood the question.

Comment: @WebpopAbdallahWebpop please kindly clarify and confirm if this is what you requirement was.